# Spring Boot - JUnit Error testing MultiPartFile Image Upload RestController with MockMvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I'm trying to test a controller class that upload an image. The endpoint receives a long Id and a MultipartFile file. The code of the controller is:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{userId}/image")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public UserDto uploadProfileImage(@PathVariable Long userId, @RequestParam("image")  MultipartFile image) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    User user =  imageService.uploadImage(userId,image);
    return UserMapper.makeDto(user);
}
```

And the test is:

```
@Test
public void whenUploadingImageThenReturnTheUser()throws Exception{

    MockMultipartFile uploadFile = new MockMultipartFile("uploadFile", new byte[1]);
    User user = new User("email@mail.com","pass", "name","lastNmae","description","123123",null);

    when(imageService.uploadImage(1L,uploadFile)).thenReturn(user);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/v1/users/"+1L+"/image").file(uploadFile).accept(contentType)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

    String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

    UserDto userDto =asObject(content);
    assertEquals(userDto.getFirstName(),user.getFirstName());
}
```

When I run the test the console shows:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :400

at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:665)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
at com.empresa.mascotar.userService.controllers.UserControllerTest.whenUploadingImageThenReturnTheUser(UserControllerTest.java:165)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
```

I don't know why I get a 400 code response.

Could you help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `new MockMultipartFile("image", new byte[1]);` ("image" instead of "uploadFile")

Comment: There is no `image` request parameter.

Comment: Ooh, what a stupid error. Thank you very much guys! It's working now! :)